# Python: force every import to reload

Tags: python, metaprogramming, python-import, monkeypatching

Is there a way to force `import x` to always reload `x` in Python (i.e., as if I had called `reload(x)`, or `imp.reload(x)` for Python 3)? Or in general, is there some way to force some code to be run every time I run `import x`?  I'm OK with monkey patching or hackery.

I've tried moving the code into a separate module and deleting `x` from `sys.modules` in that separate file. I dabbled a bit with import hooks, but I didn't try too hard because according to the documentation, they are only called after the sys.modules cache is checked. I also tried monkeypatching `sys.modules` with a custom dict subclass, but whenever I do that, `from module import submodule` raises `KeyError` (I'm guessing `sys.modules` is not a real dictionary).

Basically, I'm trying to write a debugging tool (which is why some hackery is OK here). My goal is simply that `import x` is shorter to type than `import x;x.y`.

Comment: If you really want to change the semantics of the `import` statement, you will have to patch the interpreter.  `import` checks whether the named module already is loaded and if so it does nothing more.  You would have to change exactly that, and that is hard-wired in the interpreter.  Maybe you can live with patching the Python sources to use `myImport('modulename')` instead of `import modulename`?  That would make it possible within Python itself.

Comment: @Alfe: I think this comment deserves being posted as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a lead from Alfe's answer, I got it to work like this. This goes at the module level.

```
def custom_logic():
    # Put whatever you want to run when the module is imported here

# This version is run on the first import
custom_logic()

def __myimport__(name, *args, **kwargs):
    if name == 'x': # Replace with the name of this module
        # This version is run on all subsequent imports
        custom_logic()
    return __origimport__(name, *args, **kwargs)

# Will only be run on first import
__builtins__['__origimport__'] = __import__
__builtins__['__import__'] = __myimport__
```

We are monkeypatching `__builtins__`, which is why `__origimport__` is defined when `__myimport__` is run.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to change the semantics of the `import` statement, you will have to patch the interpreter.  `import` checks whether the named module already is loaded and if so it does nothing more.  You would have to change exactly that, and that is hard-wired in the interpreter.

Maybe you can live with patching the Python sources to use `myImport('modulename')` instead of `import modulename`?  That would make it possible within Python itself.

Comment: Hmm, monkey patching `__import__`. I didn't think of that.